# WordPress remove_menu_page() function throws an error

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am trying to remove a few top-level menus on the WordPress admin panel. Oddly enough, I get an error message from the `plugin.php` file, where the function is declared, saying:

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress-alut\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php on line 1261`

I went to the file and found the following code:

```
function remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) {
    global $menu;

    foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) { // **this is line 1261**
        if ( $menu_slug == $item[2] ) {
            unset( $menu[$i] );
            return $item;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It is important to note that when I use `remove_submenu_page()`, which is the next function in `plugin.php`, I get no such error.
My function, located in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mf_remove_menu_pages' );
function mf_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
    remove_menu_page('index.php');
    remove_menu_page('users.php');
    remove_menu_page('upload.php');
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
    remove_menu_page('post-new.php');
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','themes.php');
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','theme-editor.php');
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','widgets.php');
};
```

Comment: do they need `.php` at the end?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're calling `mf_remove_menu_pages()` before `$menu` is actually set up, or it seems in cases when `$menu` is never set up. You need to wait for the `admin_menu` hook in order to actually call `remove_menu_page()`. If you're doing it on `admin_init`, then you're using the wrong hook, and that's why it's borking on AJAX requests

So you need to change your hook. Please try with this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mf_remove_menu_pages' );
function mf_remove_menu_pages() {
   remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
   remove_menu_page('index.php');
   remove_menu_page('users.php');
   remove_menu_page('upload.php');
   remove_menu_page('tools.php');
   remove_menu_page('edit.php');
   remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
   remove_menu_page('post-new.php');
   remove_submenu_page('themes.php','themes.php');
   remove_submenu_page('themes.php','theme-editor.php');
   remove_submenu_page('themes.php','widgets.php');
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thx u very much, saved me too much time

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of WordPress, to remove some subpages like `theme-editor.php` (or subpages introduced by the Jetpack plugin) you have to bind to the `admin_menu` hook with a very high priority.

E.g. to remove `theme-editor.php` you need to set a priority of about `120`. For Jetpack pages, you need somthing around `2000`.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mf_remove_menu_pages', 120 );
function mf_remove_menu_pages() {
   remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
   remove_menu_page('index.php');
   remove_menu_page('users.php');
   remove_menu_page('upload.php');
   remove_menu_page('tools.php');
   remove_menu_page('edit.php');
   remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
   remove_menu_page('post-new.php');
   remove_submenu_page('themes.php','themes.php');
   remove_submenu_page('themes.php','theme-editor.php');
   remove_submenu_page('themes.php','widgets.php');
}
```

This is also stated in the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page#Notes) and at the [Wordpress Support Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/conflict-with-ajax-due-to-debug-warning).