# HP message: PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in plugin.php

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I'm getting tons of errors in my error log.
Does anyone has a an idea how to fix this?

they are all the same:

[Mon Jun 27 12:39:xx.518352 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4663:tid 139793920644864] [client 84.80.28.xx:52348] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/685947.example.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1779', referer: https://example.com/mijn-account/

this is the code from that (default wordpress file):

```
function remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) {
    global $menu;

    foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) {
        if ( $menu_slug === $item[2] ) {
            unset( $menu[ $i ] );
            return $item;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: this is the code in the php file

unction remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) {
 global $menu;

 foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) {
  if ( $menu_slug === $item[2] ) {
   unset( $menu[ $i ] );
   return $item;
  }
 }

 return false;
}

Comment: You certainly want to return `$menu` instead of `$item`.

Comment: You should check if $menu is an array like `if (!is_array($menu)) return false;` before running the foreach.

Comment: Considering this is a core Wordpress file, I wouldn't change anything in that file. You're probably calling `remove_menu_page` incorrectly. See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove_menu_page-e_warning-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052416/wordpress-function-remove-menu-page-throws-an-error

Answer (score 0):

Probably the value that the variable ($menu) is receiving is not an array.

It would be interesting to add a validation, for example:

```
function remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) {
    global $menu;
    
    if (!is_array($menu)) return false;

    foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) {
        if ( $menu_slug === $item[2] ) {
            unset( $menu[ $i ] );
            return $item;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```